# using kyverno instead of apparmor

Tags: linux, kubernetes, apparmor, kyverno

we want to use AppArmor for pod and container security. we have Kyverno and it's possible to add some capabilities using that.
I want to know if it is possible to replace AppArmor with Kyverno for our needs in kubernetes? I mean is it possible to create policies to add or remove any capabilities from containers?